# How do I change the cursor size using python?

Tags: python, win32gui, win32con

How do you change the size of the cursor using python? I spent a while trying to find how you could do it in Python, and I heard about win32. I tried to code a script that would only change the cursor .cur file, not resize it, but it didn't change the cursor image:

```
import win32gui
import win32con

x = win32gui.LoadImage(0, r'C:\Windows\\Cursors\\aero_nwse_l.cur', 
                                win32con.IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE);
win32gui.SetCursor(x)
```

Does anyone know what I could do to make this work and how I could change this code so that it changes the size of the cursor?

Comment: Try `pyglet`.https://pythonhosted.org/pyglet/programming_guide/changing_the_mouse_cursor.html

Comment: The code in the article doesn't change my cursor.